# Position control and label horizontally

Tags: asp.net

I am asking myself why this is showing the TextBox and the Label horizontally:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" onkeypress="return CheckValid();"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="lblErrorBirthDay" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="(***)" Visible="false"></asp:Label><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="(*)" ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It gives the result:

`|__________________|(***)`

And this

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="txtDateFrom" runat="server" CssClass="txtLongerBlack12" ></dx:ASPxDateEdit>
        <asp:Label ID="lblErrorBirthDay" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="(***)" Visible="false"></asp:Label><asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="(*)" ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

gives

```
|__________________|
(***)
```

What do I have to do so that the second snipped will also be shown both controls (DateEdit and Label) horizontally?

Comment: Set a width to your `td`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the ASPxDateEdit control is outputting a block level HTML element, such as a `<div>`, which means that the `<span>` output by the Label will go underneath. You can control this with CSS, such as floating both the elements left.